# android view layout. make view fill space between views

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create a layout with basically a head, body, and footer. The `ViewPager` I am using is filling the space behind the footer content though. How can I make it not do this, and cutoff at the start of the footer content?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.janedoe.anothertabexample.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mileage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0.0 mi"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mileage"
            android:text="Stop" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't want the color(which is just the content) to run past the `Buttons` and `TextViews` on the bottom. I've tried the `layout_gravity` method as well as setting the `viewpager` to `layout_above` and `layout_blow` but neither appear to work. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: give some background color to your RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You view pager will consume all space available.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"/>
```

I would try switching to a LinearLayout and use the "android:layout_weight" property to force the ViewPager to only use available space.

Comment: Oh I think I figured it out. When I previously tried using `layout_weight` I had read to set the `ViewPager` to 1 and the rest to 0. I set the `RelativeLayout` to 3 and the `ViewPager` to 1 and now it all looks great! Just didn't experiment enough I guess.

Comment: Android layouts take a bit of getting used to :) keep practicing and they will become natural to you!

Answer (score 0):

your RelativeLayout should have android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
```

Remove android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" from all its child.

and your viewpager should look like below

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeFooter"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"/>
```

Finally your whole layout should be like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeFooter"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"/>

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mileage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0.0 mi"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/time"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mileage"
        android:text="Stop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```